For QC hardware, is there an usecase/need for higher quality semiconductor crystal?
Is there a requirement for higher-quality semiconductor material? For example, is higher purity required? I could imagine, that the quality of germanium, which is used for some Qubit implementations, isn't available.
Are there any interesting research results regarding the question?
Thanks for your answer!

Purity of silicon should be the same as in case of classical chips. Even in this case, it is very high, around 99.999999999 %.
However, some quantum computing application require not only pure silicon in terms of impurities but also isotopically pure material. This means that only one isotope is present in the silicon. A reason behind is to eliminate isotopes which nuclei generate magnetic moment causing disturbances in qubits based on electron spins. See more here.
Concerning articles on this topic, try to Google isotopically pure silicon quantum computing.
